# Newbie error: I am trying to deploy my first contract and get an error with the first function

Tags: solidity

When I try and complie the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract mortal{

    address owner;

    function mortal(){

        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner{

        if (msg.sender != owner){
            throw;
        }
    }

    function kill() onlyOwner{

        suicide(owner);
    }
}
```

I get the warning:

> No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".  function mortal(){
>
> ^ Spanning multiple lines.

I am sure this is a very basic newbie error but I would appreciate your help!

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I was able to figure this out. Instead of Throw I should have used revert() and instead of suicide() I should have used selfdestruct. The code now looks like:

contract mortal{

```
address public owner;

function mortal() public {

    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner{

    if(msg.sender == owner) { 
        revert();
    }else{
        _;
    }
}

function kill() onlyOwner public {

    selfdestruct(owner);
}
```

}

Many thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error. It's a warning that the default visibility is `public`.

I'd suggest you make the visibility explicit:

```
function mortal() public {
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the previous suggestion by smarx. You need to put a `_` somewhere in `modifier onlyOwner` to specify where the code it modifies will run. Then it should compile.

Eg it should probably look like this:

```
modifier onlyOwner{
    if (msg.sender != owner){
        throw;
    }
    _;
}
```

Comment: Thanks both. I am one step further but there is still one error in the code.

contract mortal{

 address public owner;

 function mortal() public {

  owner = msg.sender;
 }

 modifier onlyOwner{
 
  if (msg.sender != owner){
   throw;
  }else{
   _;
  }
 }

 function kill() onlyOwner{

  suicide(owner);
 }
}

I now get the error that it will not compile because throw is deprecated:

"throw" is deprecated in favour of "revert()", "require()" and "assert()".
   throw;
   ^---^
Any ideas what this could be?

Thanks a million for your help.